# LEFT OUTER JOIN 3 TABLES -SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I need to join 3 tables using left outer join .Let me give you an example using 3 tables .In the below image we can see Table:**[A.TableMaster]** the drugDescription Column must be equal to Table:**[C.Table2]**-DrugDescription column **[A.drugDescription=C.DrugDescription]** and **[C.drug=B.drug]** according to the drug the **Price** is to be assigned from Table:**[B.Table1]** .
and also with the **b.date**

in simple english the user selects a date for the particular drug and price assigned for the drug

*Image of the Tables*:[TableMaster,Table1,Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi1MM.jpg)
[image]

e.g

```
case WHEN Drug='OCTAGAM' THEN [b.price],
```

but i m not able to relate with the outer join and the three table seems confusing please Help..

Comment: Looking at that screenshot. I wonder if those prices can really be linked just on the drugname & nearest date. I would expect that there should be a different price for each codefull?

Comment: it cannot have a different price for codefull

Comment: Somehow I don't get the problem. What do you mean with "can not relate with the outer join"? I might be mistaken, but I guess the query is simple as that: `SELECT a.*, c.Price FROM TableMaster AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS b ON b.DrugDescription = a.DrugDescription LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS c ON c.Drug = b.Drug AND c.Date = a.Date` - But I guess you already tried this?

Comment: @Tyron78 Thank you ,its working

Comment: @Claricia Glad I could help. Then please be so kind and accept the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the query is simple as that:

```
SELECT a.*, c.Price
  FROM TableMaster AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS b ON b.DrugDescription = a.DrugDescription
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS c ON c.Drug = b.Drug
    AND c.Date = a.Date
```